# How to make Xcode show compile errors in header?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compilation

Xcode for now doesn't show me any compile errors, even if I purposely put there error statements it shows me "Build Succeeded". I already added this headers to the public section of Headers in Build Phases and also to Copy Files section in the same tab. I'll greatly appreciate any help since I have no clue what's wrong.

Comment: Headers only get compiled if one of your source files #includes them.

Comment: Ah, here what it was, that's true - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this question shows as unanswered so I'll just copy @Paul's answer.

> Headers only get compiled if one of your source files `#import`s them.